# How to prevent people from sharing your images once downloaded?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, web

Me and a friends are going to start up a website where we sell images for educational purposes. However, as being the website designer and coder, one of the things that bother me is that once a person buy a copy, they can simply upload it for free or give it to their friends once downloaded. Therefore completely shutting down the business and making it pointless to sell in the first place.

I was wondering if there was a way to protect these images from being shared or simply being "given out" for free. Of course we could make account from which people could access the images from but that would make one of our feature "offline usage" completely pointless. Is there any other better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't, it's impossible, don't bother wasting time on a solution. People can trivially circumvent or remove whatever protections you introduce. The only solution is not to care about it, or attempt to enforce your copyright through legal means.

Comment: Also, don't build a business model around simply selling images. Build a site that does something new or novel with those images, and make the actual sale of the images a secondary feature. If all your sites does it try and prevent people from getting images for free, you're more or less doomed from the start. That is a pretty saturated market.

Comment: That's what are intention is. We make those images for educational purposes, more specifically for SAT and other entrance test students/takers. We would like to sell these images for review and more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no technological way to enforce copyright. DRM doesn't work on complex systems where the hardware vendors collaborate to try to enforce it, let alone on open standards. Use copyright law instead.

Comment: How can I get copyright laws internationally? Since people around the world would be allowed to download.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention